# How to send data to remote server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, remote-server

I need to send data to a remote server using javascript. How do I do this?

**Background info:**
There's a webpage from which I extract some information using JS, and I need to send it back to another server for processing. Response is not neccesary. The data is XML, Which I've URLencode'd.

How would one do this?

**EDIT**

The server I'm requesting the data from is not the same that receives the data. Just to clarify.

Comment: Use XMLHttpRequest - you also need to check cross-domain policy?

Comment: What kind of endpoint do you have on the remote server?  Can it communicate over HTTP?

Comment: What do You mean by this? If what Youre asking is, does it have a webserver on it, then Yes, it does!

Comment: javaScript compulsory ? why not jQuery ?

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript... And jQuery has no better luck doing cross domain access than plain Ajax

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the most common ways to do this is AJAX. Here's how you perform an AJAX post request using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.post('/remote-url', {xml: yourXMLString });
</script>
```

On the server side you process it like any other POST request. If you're using PHP it's `$xml = $_POST['xml'];`

The biggest limitation of AJAX is that you're only allowed to make requests to the same domain the document has been loaded from (aka cross-domain policy). There are various ways to overcome this limitation, one of the easiest one is [JSONP](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/).

---

**UPD.** For cross-domain requests an extremely simple (though not universal) solution would be:

```
(new Image).src = 'http://example.com/save-xml?xml=' + escape(yourXMLString)
```

This will issue a GET request (which cannot exceed 2KB in Internet Explorer). If you absolutely need a POST request or support for larger request bodies you can either use an intermediate server-side script on your domain or you can post a dynamically created html form to iframe.

Comment: Please read the question again. I explicitly pointed out, that it was a remote server, meaning, that it is not the same that the page is loaded from.

Comment: @Janis Please make yourself familiar with what remote server is. Remote server is a "computer that is not attached to a user's keyboard but over which he or she has some degree of control, whether it is in the same room, another part of a building, or another part of the world. Also called remote computer or remote host". Btw, I addressed cross-domain requests in my answer.

Comment: I think here JSONP would work like the image. Since there is no need for a return, the image should be enough. +1 for the update and the (new Image).src syntax.

Answer (score 6):

- submit a form using POST. That is working on all browsers cross domains. Have the server process the post. the form can be submitted to a hidden frame if you want to simulate AJAX
- Use [Cross Domain Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) ([MDC](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)) ([IE XDR](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cor-blimey-cross-domain-ajax-is-really-here))
- use a web bug (create an image, set the source to the url you want - smallish GET requests only)

  `var img = new Image();`
  `img.src="http://www.otherserver.com/getxml?xml="+encodeURIComponent(yourXML);`
  (Oops, I see Lebedev did more or less the same in his update)
- use a [proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy), i.e. have your server talk to the other server for you

Answer (score 0):

Look into Javascript's XMLHTTPRequest method -- or start with a Google search for AJAX.  There's lots of ways to do this -- including some very easy ways through JS libraries like jQuery -- but a more specific answer would require some more specifics on the specific technologies you're using.

**EDIT**: You can set up the AJAX request to post to a server-side script (acting as a proxy) on your own domain, and have that script turn around and post the data to your remote server.

Comment: Wouldn't there be cross server issue ?