# sending data to server with javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i send a string value to a sever with java script without submit method?
i know i can use jquery or ajax but is there any other way to do that without any library? 
i searched in Google and i find some good links:
[How to send data to remote server using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049635/how-to-send-data-to-remote-server-using-javascript)
http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/154271-post-data-server-javascript-client-side

but all of them said we should use jquery or ajax

Comment: Ajax is not a library, it's a technique and works in every browser. That said, depending on what kind of data you want to send and what you want to do with  it, there are other ways. If you read the answers in the question you linked to properly, you will see that alternatives to Ajax are mentioned as well.

Comment: You still could use ajax without jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX isn't a library - it's built into Javascript, and is available on pretty much all browsers from even IE6 onwards.

You can find full tutorials and instruction here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: More detailed information can be found at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that what you have to do if you don't want to refresh the page. Although, you could find other framework rather than jQuery. That framework still use ajax technology inside.

Comment: @infinity: Which browsers exactly?

Comment: @infinity: IE6 definitely does Ajax. IE5 probably not. But given that IE6 is already ancient, you should certainly not worry about IE5. And I said, the question you linked already mentions alternatives, have you already tried them?