# Post data from an html to a remote asp.net server (.aspx.vb)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net, jquery

I have a `.html` page which has a reference to a remote javascript file `Data.js`. In `Data.js` there is a function which calls `navigator.appName` and assigns the generated value to a `HiddenField` already defined in my `.html` page.

**Page.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://server.com/Data.js" ></script> 
    </head>
    <body style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt" onload="Execution();">
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="Hidden2" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Data.js**

```
function Myfunction()
{
var val = navigator.appName;
document.getElementByID('Hidden2').value = val
}
```

I also had another function in place to post `Hidden2` value to a remote server in order to store it in a database such as follows:

```
    function POSTHidden() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://server.com/VB.aspx/GETHidden",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#Hidden2")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
```

And a third function which executes the first function `MyFunction();` then the second function `POSTHidden();` as follows:

```
function Execution()
{
myFunction();
POSTHidden();
}
```

Now on my `VB.aspx` there is a `WebMethod` called `GETHidden` which basically passes a string as an argument and store it in the database such as follows:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GETHidden(ByVal value As String) As String
Dim value = String.Empty
Dim str = value.Split(New Char() {" "c})
Dim conn As String

conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connStr").ConnectionString
Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conn)

Try
sqlcon.Open()
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into table (Record1) values (@param)", sqlcon)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
sqlcon.Close()

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
End Function
```

All of the above works **ONLY IF** the `.html` page is in the same domain as the `ajax request` is generated from or the `VB.aspx` is located according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049635/how-to-send-data-to-remote-server-using-javascript). As I have tried moving the `.html` out of the domain I usually upload to and upload it onto another domain, when opening the `.html`, it doesn't work whereas it works if it is in the same domain name. What I am trying to achieve is that to have a `.html` file located anywhere and when running, the data collected from the referenced `Data.js` should be posted to the remote server and stored in the database. Therefore, the `.html` page should work from anywhere remotely (despite the domain it is in or whether on the local PC) and the data should be passed or posted to the remote server (via an ajax request or any POST request that could solve the problem) so that `Hidden2` can be stored in the database. Bearing in mind, browser compatibility and multiple-users opening the page at the same time (multi-post requests to server). Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify access control header in the server side to process cross domain requests

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

HTTP access control (CORS)

Refer these. Its a little bit tricky in .net comparing to other

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/cross-domain-asp-net-web-api-call-using-ajax